# Guardar saltos de linea de textarea

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy utilizando php y mysql, necesito remplazar los saltos de linea que coloco en mi textarea por **\n** para asi guardarlo en mi base de datos, queria saber como puedo hacer esto. Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo que utilices la función `nl2br`.

Ésta función lo que hace es reemplazar los **\n** por **`<br>`**.

Acá te dejo una url:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php

La función inversa no existe, pero sí puedes crear una función con **regex**, de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

    function br2nl($string)
    {
        return preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $string);
    }

?>
```

Comment: `(\s*)?` es exactamente lo mismo que `\s*`, no hace falta escapar los `<>`, e incluso permitiría espacios al inicio de la etiqueta --> `'#<\s*br[^>]*/?>#i'`